# ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins

I have frequent git issue on jenkins while trying to do git fetch

I'm not sure why it happens on random builds and how we could solve this issue

```
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress -- ssh://git@test.git +refs/heads/development:refs/remotes/origin/development +refs/heads/release_*:refs/remotes/origin/release_* +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master # timeout=45
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@test.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:998)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1239)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1299)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:155)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:309)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress -- ssh://git@test.git +refs/heads/development:refs/remotes/origin/development +refs/heads/release_*:refs/remotes/origin/release_* +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: git fetch-pack: expected ACK/NAK, got 'ERR upload-pack: not our ref 7e26b93e8ccc53a556747e106033aaf7e80b9fb8'
fatal: git upload-pack: not our ref 7e26b93e8ccc53a556747e106033aaf7e80b9fb8

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2450)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:573)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:996)
    ... 8 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Your error is `fatal: git fetch-pack: expected ACK/NAK, got 'ERR upload-pack: not our ref`. Are you [using sub-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309538/what-does-upload-pack-not-our-ref-mean-when-fetching-git-refs-via-tags). Maybe you need to `git submodule init` ?

Comment: Your jgit implementation of Git isn't talking correctly with your cgit implementation of Git, for some reason. You could try upgrading or downgrading either side of the connection.

Comment: @IanW I deleted submodules on some branches but it still exists on others, I'm not sure that deleting submodules on all branches will solve the issue

Comment: Sorry, can't help more, but starting w/clean workspace probably helps addresses the issue, per other comments. More relaible build, but takes time to D/L repo each time.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to delete the project under Jenkins workspace and rebuild it